# How to reverse (or scale down) dithering made by alternating two pixels?

Tags: image-processing, image-scaling

I am looking for the formula (and its explanation) that gives the perceived color resulting from a quincunx arrangement of two other colors. The result is obviously not linear, because if I create an image with alternated RGB colors #E00000 (red) and #0000E0 (blue), and compare it with the mathematical average #700070, I see a big difference on the rendering.

On the image below, the left part is composed with #E00000 and #0000E0 colors, while the right is only #700070:

[image: Comparison with #700070]

I know there is a solution, because when I use GIMP to unzoom the dithered part, it magically continues to show the exact color I feel, but this time with an effective RGB code, which is #980098. This conversion is also made by the scaling feature when I select the "linear" algorithm... (Well, am I wrong, or despite its name it does not produces linearity at all?)

On the image below, the left part has still no purple in its pixels, whereas the right part is the #980098 purple:

[image: Comparison with #980098]

At least under my screen, if I don't look too carefully this image, it looks like a single purple band with no variation.

So what is the formula, and why? How to mathematically get this #980098 from #E00000 and #0000E0?

Comment: On my screen, the first block appears all a single color, and the second one is clearly split with the right half being considerably lighter.  So the "right" answer is very dependent on the gamma of your display.

Comment: @ChrisDodd yes, gamma is critically important for a convincing illusion.  The best you can do is sRGB, it won't be perfect but should be close enough most of the time.

Comment: So this fact may be screen-dependent. If so, this is odd because it would mean GIMP decided to apply my screen specific settings to a persistent image scaling, which could give a wrong appearance with another person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the following conversion procedure is applied:

- Convert color levels from [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) to Linear RGB color space (inverse gamma).
- Compute the average color in Linear RGB color space.
- Convert the average from Linear RGB to sRGB color space (apply gamma).

Computing the average in Linear RGB color space gives better perceived output, compared to computing the average in sRGB color space.
That is because the gamma correction (used with sRGB) makes sRGB color space non-linear.

I thought that computing the average in [LAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space) color space supposed to give better results, but at least for the given example, Linear RGB result looks better.

---

MATLAB code sample (note that your input sample is `#0000D0` and not `#0000E0`):

```matlab
% Create the dithering sample - used as reference
I = zeros(100, 100, 3, 'uint8');
I(1:2:end, 1:2:end, 1) = hex2dec('D0'); % Red
I(2:2:end, 2:2:end, 1) = hex2dec('D0'); % Red
I(1:2:end, 2:2:end, 3) = hex2dec('D0'); % Blue
I(2:2:end, 1:2:end, 3) = hex2dec('D0'); % Blue
figure;imshow(I);impixelinfo % Show I for testing


% Convert the red and blue values from sRGB to linear RGB
lin_red = rgb2lin(im2double(uint8([hex2dec('D0'), 0, 0])));  % #D00000
lin_blue = rgb2lin(im2double(uint8([0, 0, hex2dec('D0')]))); % #0000D0

% Compute the average in Linear RGB color space
average_lin_lab = (lin_red + lin_blue) / 2;

% Convert from Linear RGB to sRGB
average_rgb = im2uint8(lin2rgb(average_lin_lab)); % [152 0 152] = #980098

% Fill J matrix with the average color in sRGB color space
J = zeros(100, 100, 3, 'uint8');
J(:, :, 1) = average_rgb(1); % Red color channel
J(:, :, 2) = average_rgb(2); % Green color channel
J(:, :, 3) = average_rgb(3); % Blue color channel
figure;imshow(J);impixelinfo % Show the result for testing
```

---

Result (`I` and `J` images):
[image][image]

The RGB values of `J` are exactly #980098.

Comment: Oh yes, I may have changed the value from 0xE0 to 0xD0 during the tests. My bad.
Anyway, thanks for this magnificent answer, I didn't know the Linear RGB. If I understand things well, this is also what the Wiki page calls CIE XYZ (they say it is 'sometimes called "linear values"'), at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Transformation
I tried to retrieve the value manually with their conversion formula, and the result is near: ((1.055 × (((208÷255 + 0.055)÷1.055)^2.4)÷2)^(1÷2.4) - 0.055)×255 = 147.19124
The result is also a little lesser with extra tests, but I'm OK with that approximation.

Comment: Inverse gamma: `(((208/255 + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4)*255`  = `160.84` then average with `0`, we get `80.42`. Applying forward gamma correction: `round(((80.42/255)^(1/2.4)*1.055 - 0.055)*255)` = `152`.

Comment: CIE XYZ is used as an "intermediate color space" - used for converting between colors spaces. Linear RGB is a nickname for sRGB without gamma correction. We may also name it "Linear sRGB", but it's confusing.

Comment: Okay I see, I was just computing (1.055C)^(1/2.4) instead of 1.055(C^(1/2.4)).
Well, if they have different uses, are CIE XYZ and Linear RGB two different things that have the same formula?

Comment: They are two different things, and don't have the same formula... When converting from sRGB to CIE XYZ, the first step is converting from sRGB to Linear RGB.